# Forgot to use `rails console --sandbox` -- how to undo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I played around with creating some users and inserting a few row into my table without using `--sandbox`.

How to undo this? I suspect it is not `db:rollback` since `migrate` and `rollback` is to modify table features (like adding columns, add index, etc.), not about inserting / removing data.

EDIT: I'm using `sqlite3`

Comment: I would just delete them in the console.  I can't think of any way you could roll back, without reverting the whole database/table to an earlier saved copy.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I think you are going to have to manually revert your changes in the console.  If it had been MySQL or Oracle I might have been able to help.